# Editing SPI bus on Raspberry Pi 4 in device tree

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi, raspberry-pi4, device-tree

I have been looking into adding a 5th wire to the SPI bus. This is essentially a slave ready line. I know that you have to edit the device tree but do I have to edit each SPI dts file or can I just add a new file to the raspberry pi device tree?

Comment: You would only modify the one **.dts** file you use (compile & install) for *your* board.   You can even rename the **.dts** file to whatever you choose, so long as you make this name change downstream, e.g. in installation scripts, boot loading commands, etc.